# little bit confuse in dgetting absolute url in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

```
#project url

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

import products

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('products.urls')),
    url(r'^product/(?P<title>[\w-]+)/$', products.views.single,name='single')



]

# app url
from django.urls import path, include

import products
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),

]
 #model
class products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    desc = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=29.99)
    sales_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_price(self):
        return self.price

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("single", kwargs={"title": self.title})
#views
def home(request):
    product = products.objects.all()
    template = 'home.html'

    context = {'product': product}

    return render(request, template, context)

def single(request,title):
    try:
        product = products.objects.get(title=title)
        template = 'products.html'
        context = {'product': product}
        return render(request, template, context)
    except:
        raise Http404
```

plz view my code .. i m littlebit confuse in absolute url.. it returns title of the product after clicking some link but it doesnt give me the title if i change produc to other. for eg:http:/127.0.0.1:8000/product/T-shirt/ gives title but wheni hit http:/127.0.0.1:8000/productS/T-shirtgives eroror

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what your actual problem is from the way you've expressed your question, but there are several issues:

- Models, unless a single entity represents a plurality of something, must be named in singular. Also, following Python practices, they should be capitalized.

  - `class products(...)` should be `class Product(...)`.
- Since `title` is not an unique field, as soon as you have multiple products named "T-shirt", your `single` view will crash, since `.get()` refuses to work if more than one object matches the query.

  - Rethink your URL scheme (to e.g. use that unique `slug` field you have).
- The `product/.../` URL should be in `products/urls.py`, not your project URLs.

  - Move it there.
- Unless you're absolutely sure what you're doing, don't use a bare `except:`, since it will happily hide *any* exception. You're looking for `except ObjectDoesNotExist:`, probably.
- You should consider using generic class-based views.

Comment: i have done as u said.. my queston is that i am using reverse because in future if i change the url it doesnt affects later. when i go to browser and hit product/T-shirt it returns slug of that Obj but i think it must return same when i change products to product then if not whats the meaaning of using reverse?

Comment: `reverse()` looks up URLs by the `name=...` you set in the `urls.py` file(s), so you don't have to type them out both in `get_absolute_url()` etc. _and_ `urls.py`. It won't help you redirect e.g. `products/foo/` to `product/foo/` if you change your URL structure later though; you'd want to set up redirect views for that.